# Registrar un ModelBinderProvider con Autofac en ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, binding, inyeccion-de-dependencias, autofac

Para una aplicación ASP.NET MVC5 he creado un ModelBinderProvider para cierto tipo de datos.

Si añado el nuevo ModelBinderProvider a la colección BinderProviders en el Global.asax funciona perfectamente.

```
ModelBinderProviders.BinderProviders.Add(new CustomModelBinderProvider());
```

En la aplicación estoy utilizando Autofac como IoC el cual me permite registrar por ejemplo mis ModelBinders personalizados:

```
Autofac.Integration.Mvc.RegistrationExtensions.AsModelBinderForTypes(
    builder.RegisterType<CustomModelBinder>(), typeof(CustomModel));
```

Pero no he encontrado la forma de registrar el ModelProvider con Autofac.

¿Existe la forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado:

```
builder.Register(c => new CustomModelBinderProvider())
   .As<IModelBinderProvider>()
```

Answer (score 0):

Has aplicado en dicha clase el atributo Autofac.Integration.Mvc.ModelBinderTypeAttribute ?

Luego para registrar deberías hacer

```
builder.RegisterModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();
```

La fuente de esta respuesta puedes echarle un ojo a http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html

Comment: Hola Sergio,
pero el atributo ModelBinderTypeAttribute sirve para registrar ModelBinders, que se puede hacer así con el método AsModelBinderForTypes que pongo más arriba o con el método RegisterModelBinders. El problema es que yo trato de registrar un ModelBinderProvider.